# looking for a less awkward way of returning a variable if it exisits

Tags: php, if-statement, return

I have this snippet of code inside a `foreach` loop:

```
if ($foo) {
   return $foo;
}
```

Basically, I'm creating an early exit out of my function if `$foo` is found to exist.

Does PHP have a better way of writing this? I was considering the ternary operator, but I don't think it applies in this case...

Comment: What exactly do you not like about doing it like this?

Comment: What's wrong with `if(isset($foo)){return $foo;}`?

Comment: This is a totally normal way to exit a foreach. Unless you could loop with a while(!$foo).

Comment: Define `exist`. If you simply mean `non-empty value` then explain how the if statement you've posted is awkward.

Comment: By `exist` I mean non-NULL. Looking at my code,it just seemed like a clunky way to write this logic. @Vyktor, your suggestion looks more expressive

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments... You should use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function.

```
foreach(...) {
    if( !is_null($foo)){
        return $foo;
    }
}

throw new Exception( 'No $foo found');
```